# Using chaiAsPromised to test if object in collection has key

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, es6-promise

I have a promise function `project_list` which returns an array objects like the below

`[{foo:'k',bar:'j'}]`

I have two questions

1. Is there a way to check if the a given key exists in the array?

i tried the below , but unfortunately - it seems to only check for values as opposed to keys

```
 it('should return an array of objects containing project_details',function(){
    return expect(project_list(data)).to.eventually.have.deep.property('[0]','foo')
  })
```

2. Is there a way to test multiple assertions on one promise object? I.e - can i have multiple expect statements for one promise function?

i tried this

```
  it('should return an array of objects containing project_details',function(done){
    project_list(data).then(function(result){
      expect(result)[0].to.have.key('foo')
      expect(result)[0].to.have.key('bar')
      done()
    })
  })
```

I get a timeout error when i try to test the above.

So instead , i structure the test in this way

```
  before(function(done){
    project_list(data).then(function(results){
      console.log(results)
      result = results;
      done()
    })
  })

  it('should retrieve a list',function(){
    expect(result).to.be.an('array')
  })

  it('should return an array of objects containing project_details',function(){
    expect(result[0]).to.contain.keys('foo')
  })
```

this seems to work. but i would like to know if theres a better waty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `property`, the 2nd argument is the *value* of the property addressed in the first argument. If you only want to check that the property exists, then you should not have a 2nd argument, and the 1st should be the *entire path* to the property.

As for doing multiple expects, yes, you can. You just need to write your `expect` calls properly. `expect(result)[0]` makes no sense. And you should check how [`keys`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_keys) (aka `key`) works. If you do not specify `any` or `all`, then `all` is the default and so both your expects would fail due to this. In the example below, I've chosen `any` for the purpose of a) illustrating multiple `expect`s and b) having the test pass. The two calls could have been combined into: `expect(result[0]).to.have.all.keys('foo', 'bar');`

Here's an illustration, based on the code in your question:

```
var chai = require("chai");
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
var expect = chai.expect;

var value = [{foo:'k', bar:'j'}];
function project_list() {
    return Promise.resolve(value);
}

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

it("test 1", function () {
    return expect(project_list()).to.eventually.have.deep.property('[0].foo');
});

it('test 2',function(){
    return project_list().then(function(result){
        expect(result[0]).to.have.any.key('foo');
        expect(result[0]).to.have.any.key('bar');
    });
});
```

Comment: You can also use the `all` construct: `expect(result[0]).to.have.all.keys('foo', 'bar');`

Comment: Yep, I was editing to add that while you were commenting.